# Transformation of Independent Features

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, multinomial-distribution, computational-statistics

The Residual graph looks as follows.

[image]

I have verified the distribution of independent variables and none of them are normal. Looks like, transformation to normal need to be done. Any second opinion, please

**I have looked the distribution of IV and few are in Beta and Gamma. How to transform Beta and Gamma to Normal**

Comment: Could you explain why you feel it would be useful to transform the independent variables?

Comment: I had asked this question to myself and not in favour of transformation. Although when I transform few Independent to normal (by taking log or x**2,..) then result improved. Hence I believe few more transformation may help.

Comment: It's the residuals of your dependent variable matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regression models generally do  not make *any* assumptions about the distribution of the predictor variables!  They are just taken as known constants ... Before transforming them, if you indeed decides to do so, think about that transforming them *changes the meaning of the model*, the *meaning of estimated parameters*!  Transforming predictors is usually done to obtain some specific interpretation that you want (like log transforming to be able to interpret coefficients as elasticities).